# Insert 2 rows in trigger (different tables, insert 2 must references insert1)

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I need to insert 2 rows into 2 different tables using a trigger but the public.user table needs to get the company id that I am inserting into the db within the same trigger. Is this possible? 
My other option (i think) would be to add another trigger for after inserts on public.user and update the public user created_by column using a select from the company table.

```
create or replace function public.handle_new_user() 
returns trigger as $$
begin
  -- Insert here 
  insert into public.company (created_by)
  values (new.id)

  -- need to ref public.company just inserted in this insert statement
  insert into public.users (id, email, name, company_id)
  values (new.id, new.email, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name', (select top 1 id from public.company where created_by = new.id));
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres provides the ability to return columns from the [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-insert.html). With that you can get the `id` of the `company` row just inserted.

```
create or replace function public.handle_new_user() 
returns trigger as $$
declare 
   l_company_id  public.company.id%type;  
begin
  -- Insert here 
  insert into public.company (created_by)
         values (new.id)
      returning id into l_company_id;

  -- need to ref public.company just inserted in this insert statement
  insert into public.users (id, email, name, company_id)
  values (new.id, new.email, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'full_name',  l_company_id);
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```